# How to mysql query `$wpdb->get_var` `bp_groups` in buddypress?

Tags: php, mysql, buddypress

I know that:

`$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users;");`

Can select wordpress user by mysql, but when I call a buddypress group, it failed, nothing returns

`$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->bp_groups;");`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$wpdb only stores information on the Wordpress tables.  Buddypress is going to be elsewhere.

The following page has a database map, with the default table names.  Since the 'wp_' portion isn't certain you'll want to use `$wpdb->prefix`

http://api.buddypress.org/development/legacy-analysis/data-model-1-dot-3/

So either of the following should work fine

```
$table = $wpdb->prefix."bp_groups";
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table;");
```

or inline

```
$wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {$wpdb->prefix}bp_groups;");
```

You can use that schema map as a guide to getting more information, like how many users are in certain groups, etc...

Good luck :)